# how to call a looped user input from one class method into another class method?

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming, and just started learning C# and C++. I'm building a simple program in C# that asks questions and gives users two options. I have a system for using a while loop and switch statements to determine whether the user has selected a viable option or not based on the question, but I cannot figure out how to call the method from UserChoice to Program's main method. Here is the program.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Learn_C_Sharp
{
class UserChoice
{
    public static bool loopContinue = true;
    public static void YesOrNo(string v)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 'Y' for yes or 'N' for no.\n");
        char answerYN = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        while (loopContinue)
        {
            switch (answerYN)
            {
                case 'y':
                case 'Y':
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected yes.\n");
                    loopContinue = !loopContinue;
                    break;

                case 'n':
                case 'N':
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected no.\n");
                    loopContinue = !loopContinue;
                    break;

                default:
                    loopContinue = true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    public static void LeftOrRight()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 'L' for left or 'R' for right.\n");
        char answerLR = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        while (loopContinue)
        {
            switch (answerLR)
            {
                case 'l':
                case 'L':
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected left.\n");
                    loopContinue = !loopContinue;
                    break;

                case 'r':
                case 'R':
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected right.\n");
                    loopContinue = !loopContinue;
                    break;

                default:
                    loopContinue = true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

.

```
class Program
{
   
   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name.");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + ". \n");
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try a tasty treat?\n");
        UserChoice treat = new UserChoice();
        
        
       
        
        
    }

}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks, have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically choosing between two options in both methods, so it is a perfect chance to use a `bool` return type, instead of `void`.

So when you check if it starts with y/Y you can `return true;` instead of `break;`. I will leave the second method change as an exercise for you :)

Also you declared both methods static, but created an instance of `UserChoice` in your `Main`, so probably you do not need them to be static. And you have a redundant parameter `string v` which you do not use.

So

```
public static void YesOrNo(string v)
```

becomes

```
public bool YesOrNo()
```

in `Main` you will have:

```
UserChoice treat = new UserChoice();
bool yes = treat.YesOrNo();
```

---

An error I have found in your code is that you ask for the user input *outside* of the while loop, which means, it will never get updated and will loop infinitely. Just move the ReadLine inside the while loop.

Oh, and you should keep `loopContinue` as a local variable in both methods, not a class field, because you do not need to keep the value between method invocations (on the contrary, it would lead to an error, if you call 2 successive methods, because the value would be the same from the first method call, that is false).

Comment: Happy to help :) BTW one other thing that could keep this specific code be shorter is to delete `loopContinue` totally and just use `while(true)` - but don't do this is in every while loop you will ever write! It applies only to cases like this, where your default branch just says to continue and you break/return in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

is your intention is learn c#. This is also an option.

```
class UserChoice
{
    public static void YesOrNo()
    {
        bool loopState;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 'Y' for yes or 'N' for no.\n");
            var choice = Console.ReadKey();

            // string you wants to check character                 
            switch (choice.Key) //choice.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper() // Then only check 'Y'/'N'
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Y: // Both 'Y' & 'y' accept here;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected yes");
                    loopState = false;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.N: // Both 'N' & 'n' accept here;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected No");
                    loopState = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    loopState = true;
                    break;
            }

        } while (!loopState);
    }
}
```